# NgRx - State changing improperly

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have two pages FlowGroupPanel and FlowPanel. For each of these screens I created a state management to the filter. However, when I dispatch the FlowPanel it changes the FlowGroupPanel estate. I don't know why is this happening. I added main parts of the code and also some pictures for a better understanding.

[image][image]

FilterFlowGroupPanel Actions

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { SearchFilterMessageLog } from '../models/SearchFilterMessageLog';

export enum FilterFlowGroupPanelActionTypes {
    ADDFILTER = '[Filter Flow Group Panel] Add Filter',
    CLEARFILTER = '[Filter Flow Group Panel] Clear Filter',
}

export const addFilter = createAction(
    FilterFlowGroupPanelActionTypes.ADDFILTER,
    props<{ searchFilterFlowGroupPanel: SearchFilterMessageLog }>()
)

export const clearFilter = createAction(
    FilterFlowGroupPanelActionTypes.CLEARFILTER,
    props<{ searchFilterFlowGroupPanel: null }>()
)
```

FilterFlowGroupPanel  Reducer

```
import { createReducer, props, on, State } from '@ngrx/store';
import { FilterFlowGroupPanelActions } from '../actions/action-types';
import { SearchFilterMessageLog } from '../models/SearchFilterMessageLog';

export interface FilterFlowGroupPanelState{
  filterFlowGroupPanel: SearchFilterMessageLog
}
// export const initialState = null;
const initialState: FilterFlowGroupPanelState = null



export const _filterFlowGroupPanelReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(FilterFlowGroupPanelActions.addFilter, (state, { searchFilterFlowGroupPanel }) => ({ ...state, ...searchFilterFlowGroupPanel})),
  on(FilterFlowGroupPanelActions.clearFilter, state => state )
)


export function filterFlowGroupPanelReducer(state, action) {
    return _filterFlowGroupPanelReducer(state, action);
  }
```

FlowGroupPanelModule

```
StoreModule.forFeature('filterFlowGroupPanelFeature', {
      filterFlowGroupPanel: filterFlowGroupPanelReducer,
    })
```

Dispatching

```
this.store.dispatch(FilterFlowGroupPanelActions.addFilter({searchFilterFlowGroupPanel}))
```

---

FilterFlowPanel Actions

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { SearchFilterMessageLog } from '../models/SearchFilterMessageLog';

export enum FilterFlowPanelActionTypes {
    ADDFILTER = '[Filter Flow Panel] Add Filter',
    CLEARFILTER = '[Filter Flow Panel] Clear Filter',
}

export const addFilter = createAction(
    FilterFlowPanelActionTypes.ADDFILTER,
    props<{ searchFilterFlowPanel: SearchFilterMessageLog }>()
)

export const clearFilter = createAction(
    FilterFlowPanelActionTypes.CLEARFILTER,
    props<{ searchFilterFlowPanel: null }>()
)
```

FilterFlowPanel  Reducer

```
import { createReducer, props, on, State } from '@ngrx/store';
import { FilterFlowPanelActions } from '../actions/action-types';
import { SearchFilterMessageLog } from '../models/SearchFilterMessageLog';

export interface FilterFlowPanelState{
  filterFlowPanel: SearchFilterMessageLog
}

export const initialState: FilterFlowPanelState = null

export const _filterFlowPanelReducer = createReducer(initialState,
    on(FilterFlowPanelActions.addFilter, (state,  {searchFilterFlowPanel} ) => ({ ...state, ...searchFilterFlowPanel})),
    on(FilterFlowPanelActions.clearFilter, state => state )
  )


export function filterFlowPanelReducer(state, action) {
    return _filterFlowPanelReducer(state, action);
  }
```

FlowPanelModule

```
StoreModule.forFeature('filterFlowPanelFeature', {
      filterFlowPanel: filterFlowPanelReducer,
    })
```

Dispatching

```
this.store.dispatch(FilterFlowPanelActions.addFilter({searchFilterFlowPanel}))
```

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that you're using the same reference and when you modify it in once place, the modification can be seen in the other place as well.

Comment: Hi @AndreiGătej that's a good guess. What I can't understand is why this may happening. As you can see I'm using diffent actions, reducer, etc.

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz? It would be much easier to debug this way.

Comment: This is probably because of the data in searchFilterFlowPanel ?

Comment: Hi guys. I found out what the error was. It was too silly to be honest. 
I was passing a object from FilterFlowGroupPanel to FilterFlowPanel via routing. However I was passing the reference because of that it became a messy, even on Redux flow. Wherever I update FilterFlowPanel it was referencing the same object than when I cameback to FilterFlowGroupPanel the properties were also changed.

To resolve this, I just copied the object before sendind it to the other component.

I really appreciate for your help guys